# Unable to unlock Android phone from Android Device Manager lock

Tags: huawei

My phone is a Huawei P8 Lite ALE-L21 (Running Android 6.0). An hour ago I was testing if the Android Device Manager worked for the phone by locking it and it did. Thing is when I want to unlock my phone it doesn't let me to.

The unlock screen has a number pad with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 0. There is a delete button and an Emergency Call button but there is nowhere a submit button. I cannot submit the unlock code when I type it. It says 'Your unlock password is required after a restart'. When I restart the phone it displays 'Locked by Android Device Manager' and gives an option to go to the Emergency Call screen or to input the unlock password.

I cant take a screenshot because well my phone is locked and I cant access anything except the unlock code input.

I've tried recovery via ADB but that's not an option since my glorious phone decided to unauthorized my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by restarting my phone a couple of times and inputting the first password I've set via the Android Device Manager (because I've locked it multiple times after that to attempt to 'change' the unlock password).